# How MAC (Mandatory Access Control) model prevents trojan horse attacks?

Tags: operating-systems, cryptography, security

I've heard that the MAC Model prevents Trojans to charm files on the system.
How is it possible? Can somebody show any example that MAC model protects us against it?